# CSS - using transform: translate makes black borders grey-ish

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has multilpe div child elements. When I apply "transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" it does transform it but the black borders turn grey-ish.

When I disable the transform attribute in my Dev Tools the borders are the 1px solid black I want them to have.

```css
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- More children -->
</div>
```

I want to translate the element and keep my 1px solid black borders.

With transform it looks like this: 
[image]
Without transform (and how it should look) it looks like this: [image]

Comment: can you show an example of  the child element CSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For understanding what happened, when you apply `transform: translate..` to an element, it will be converted from rendered as `vector` to `pixel`. That make it looked `grey-ish`.

Instead of apply `transform: translate..`, you can wrap it in a container and use `flex`:

```css
section{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- More children -->
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I just adding the height so it get more easy to see the border, the height will always expand based on your content by default

Comment: This worked, just added a "text-align: center;" to the section tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the height of the element you transform. If it has an even number of pixels in height, the shift by transform will be an integer number of pixel. If is is an odd pixel height, the shift will be an integer plus one half pixels.

Ths will leed to subpixel rendering. Depending on the browser, the one pixel crisp border line will be anti-aliased (e.g. Chrome does it, Firefox doesn't do it).

Here is an example:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#wrapper-2 {
  left: 55%;
  line-height: 21px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-1">
  <p>line-height: 20px;</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-2">
  <p>line-height: 21px;</p>
</div>
```

The solution would be:
As Ethan Vu said: Use a different method of centering like flex.
Or recalculate the transform by means of JS.

```js
"use strict";
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper'))

  .forEach(el => {
    // this calculates the Y-position of the element and checks, whether it is N.0 or N.5 pixels (N is integer)
    if ((el.getBoundingClientRect().y*2) % 2) {
      // shift class will calculate the transform with an calculated offset od 0.5 pixels
      el.classList.add('shift')
    }
  })
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper.shift {
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(calc(-50% + .5px));
}
#wrapper-2 {
  left: 55%;
  line-height: 21px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-1">
  <p>line-height: 20px;</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper-2">
  <p>line-height: 21px;</p>
</div>
```