# Weekday boxes have little lines or spaces between them if you look carefully. These lines or gaps are present in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, vite

I am using vite react typescript.

My App component

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My DatePicker component

```
function DatePicker() {
  return (
    <div className="datepicker-wrapper">
      <input />
      <input />

      <Calendar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Calendar Component

```
function Calendar() {
  return (
    <div className="datepicker-popper">
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Sunday</div>
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Monday</div>
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Tuesday</div>
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Wednesday</div>
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Thursday</div>
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Friday</div>
      <div className="datepicker-weekday">Saturday</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and finally my css file

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.datepicker-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  font-family: monospace;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.datepicker-popper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.8rem;
  left: 50%;

  translate: -50% 100%;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  width: 100%;

  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
}

.datepicker-weekday {
  display: block;
  background-color: palevioletred;
}
```

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdSjd.png)
**The boxes containing weekdays** **have weird space or line** **b/w them in chrome** **but not in** **firefox**.

**I tried making the container flexbox, grid. I also tried changing the div to span but none of** **them worked.**

**Here is the codesandbox link :** https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-stitch-deoc00?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.css&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A31%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D

Try running this sandbox in chrome and firefox. You will see the difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: The problem from my perspective is the `translate` property.
There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034976/css-using-transform-translate-makes-black-borders-grey-ish) with a probable explanation of why this happens.

---

If you add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.datepicker-wrapper`, it will allow the `.datepicker-popper` to fall below the inputs and you can get rid of all the absolute positioning and translating that cause the white line to appear.
It will also make your code more readable.

here is the code with the above mentioned fixes applied: https://codepen.io/Aga-K-O/pen/RwBqZWq?editors=1100

Comment: I am making a popper so i do need to use position absolute.

Comment: That changes things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just use 'normalize.css' file to avoid different results in different browsers. Normalizing file you can take from each site you have googled

Comment: Nope, this does not works and does not makes sense either.